# Ruby: what's the difference with these two Arrays?

Tags: ruby

Getting confused by syntax here, but what is the difference between:

```
foo[x][y]
```

and

```
foo[x, y]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `foo[x, n]` returns n elements from `foo` starting from the xth element.
- `foo[x][y]` finds the xth element in `foo` and returns its yth element.

Here's an example to demonstrate:

```
> foo = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11],[12,13,14]]
=> [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14]]
> foo[1,2]
=> [[3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
> foo[1][2]
=> 5
```

Answer (score 3):

The other explanations are good, but here's a different take on it.

`foo[x]` is syntactic sugar for `foo.slice(x)`. Likewise, `foo[x,y]` is equivalent to `foo.slice(x,y)`. If you look at [the rubydocs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002160) you'll see that

`array.slice(index)` returns the value at index, and

`array.slice(start,length)` with two parameters returns a subarray starting at `start` and having `length` elements.

Therefore, you can think of `foo[x][y]` as `foo.slice(x).slice(y)` which is taking the y<sup>th</sup> element from an array at position x of the `foo` array, which is obviously different from `foo[x,y]` or `foo.slice(x,y)` which is extracting a subarray of values from foo itself.

Answer (score 1):

There first syntax lets you index into a 2D array (i.e. an array of arrays) e.g.

```
irb(main):035:0> l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
irb(main):036:0> l[0]
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):037:0> l[0][0]
=> 1
```

The second returns y elements from an array starting at position x e.g.

```
irb(main):038:0> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
irb(main):039:0> a[2,3]
=> [3, 4, 5]
```